# ¿Cómo destruir una sesión al abandonar una ventana?

Tags: php, session

¿De qué manera podría usar `session_destroy()` en el momento en que se cierra una cierta página?

Comment: php no es un lenguaje de programación que manipule el cliente (navegador), solo se ejecuta del lado del servidor, no entiendo el punto de apoyar esta pregunta y darle favorito, faltaría que aprendieras más conceptos sobre php, en todo caso la pregunta sería más orientada a javascript

Answer (score 3):

Mediante PHP solamente no puedes determinar eso.
PHP es un lenguaje que se ejecuta solamente en el servidor, por lo que el navegador del cliente necesita de otra herramienta (JavaScript) para comunicarle al servidor que la ventana ha sido cerrada.

Buscando en Stack en ingles encontre esto para ti y responde a una posible solucion y probablemente la mas eficiente.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15614577/12436158

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
    // milisegundos que espera el navegador antes de cerrar la pagina
    var x = 200;
    var a = (new Date()).getTime() + x;

    // -----------
    // Llamadas asincronas o AJAX aqui, diciendole 
    // al servidor que la ventana del cliente se va a cerrar
    // -----------

    // Aqui el navegador va a esperar el valor de X milisegundos dandole 
    // tiempo a la consulta asincrona a ser enviada. 
    // Si ese tiempo no se usa, el navegador cierra la
    // ventana desechando la llamada asincrona
    while ((new Date()).getTime() < a) {}
}, false)
```

Aca tienes documentacion del evento
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp

Para lograr lo que quieres debes aprender a trabajar XMLHttpRequest
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp

O Ajax
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Luego de enviar la consulta preparas un script PHP que va a esperar la peticion.
Digamos...sesion.php

```
if(isset($_GET["cerrar_sesion"]))
{
    //Destruir sesion o variables de sesion aqui...
}
```

Comment: aunque la pregunta cumple con una respuesta válida, no entra en el contexto de resolverlo con las etiquetas que menciona el preguntador, pues en ningún momento pidió la opinión de cómo hacerlo con javascript

Comment: @FernandoUrban bueno yo tambien soy nuevo en Stack, como el que hace lapregunta. No podia dejar la respuesta simplemente con "No se pude con PHP" y no darle una direccion de como dirigirse en la solucion de su duda. Que hubieras hecho en mi lugar?

Comment: Claro, es una respuesta que da solución al problema, pero a veces no sabemos si el preguntador no podría usar javascript en ese momento y por eso pregunta cómo hacerlo con php puro, en todo caso la respuesta sería que no se puede, sin embargo tu respuesta propone sugerencias, lo cual es correcto, para solucionar el problema,